# Шапка наезжает на контент и не адаптивная таблица

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте!

Использую bootstrap. Верстку можно посмотреть на сайте [тут](http://testbl777.tk/).

Вопросы изложил на скриншотах. Подскажите, в чем ошибка и как подправить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо.

Comment: Вам действительно нужна адаптивность меньше 400px по ширине? Да и тело под шапкой у меня норм отображается...

Comment: @AGS17, ну на 5 айфоне или 6, режимы отображения которые стоят в хроме, было бы хорошо. Отоброжается то оно норм, но вот часть контента прячется под саму шапку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это

```
body.fixed-nav {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

замените на это

```
body.fixed-nav {
    padding-top: 170px;
}
```

Comment: Понял, теперь буду знать, спасибо.

Comment: Если решение подходит - нажмите на галочку

Comment: Нажму) Только там ещё 1 пункт) нажал стрелочку пока)